# Paint stroke not covering all the side in android

Tags: android

Hi i am creating indicator for doughnut chart but it is covering only three side. Here i added onDraw method.The selected chart index arc should be highlighted with indicator.The indicator should be cover all the four sides.

Code:

```
    @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int width, int height, Paint paint) {
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    int legendSize = getLegendSize(mRenderer, height / 5, 0);
    int left = x;
    int top = y;
    int right = x + width;
    int sLength = mDataset.getItemCount();
    double total = 0;
    String[] titles = new String[sLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
        total += mDataset.getValue(i);
        titles[i] = mDataset.getCategory(i);
    }
    if (mRenderer.isFitLegend()) {
        legendSize = drawLegend(canvas, mRenderer, titles, left, right, y, width, height, legendSize, paint, true);
    }
    int bottom = y + height - legendSize;

    drawBackground(mRenderer, canvas, x, y, width, height, paint, false, Renderer.NO_COLOR);
    float currentAngle = mRenderer.getStartAngle();
    float labelCurrentAngle = mRenderer.getStartAngle();
    // int mRadius = Math.min(Math.abs(right - left), Math.abs(bottom - top));
    // int radius = (int) (500 * 0.35) + 50;
    //Log.i("radius++", "" + radius);
    int mRadius = Math.min(Math.abs(right - left), Math.abs(bottom - top));
    double rCoef = 0.35 * mRenderer.getScale();
    double decCoef = 0.2 / sLength;
    int radius = (int) (mRadius * rCoef);

    if (mCenterX == 0) {
        mCenterX = (left + right) / 2;
    }
    if (mCenterY == 0) {
        mCenterY = (bottom + top) / 2;
    }

    // Hook in clip detection after center has been calculated
    mPieMap.setDimensions(radius, mCenterX, mCenterY);
    boolean loadPieCfg = !mPieMap.areAllSegmentPresent(sLength);
    if (loadPieCfg) {
        mPieMap.clearPieSegments();
    }

    float shortRadius = radius * 0.9f;
    float longRadius = radius * 1.1f;

    RectF oval = new RectF(mCenterX - radius, mCenterY - radius, mCenterX + radius, mCenterY + radius);
    for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
        float value = (float) mDataset.getValue(i);
        float angle = (float) (value / total * 360);
        int color = mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i).getColor();

        if (mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i).isClicked()) {
            ClickedArc.CANVAS = canvas;
            ClickedArc.CURRENT_ANGLE = currentAngle;
            ClickedArc.ANGLE = angle;
            ClickedArc.COLOR = color;
            ClickedArc.INDEX = mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i).getDataIndex();
        } else {
            Paint paint3 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint3.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint3.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            int[] colors = {color, color};

            RadialGradient gradient3 = new RadialGradient(mCenterX, mCenterY, radius, colors, null, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint3.setShader(gradient3);
            paint3.setAntiAlias(true);

            canvas.drawArc(oval, currentAngle, angle, true, paint3);
        }

        try {
            if (mRenderer.getRenderers().get(ClickedArc.INDEX).isClicked()) {
                Paint paint3 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                paint3.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                paint3.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                Paint shadow = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

                int[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK};
                RadialGradient gradient3 = new RadialGradient(mCenterX, mCenterY, radius, colors, null, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                shadow.setShader(gradient3);

                shadow.setAntiAlias(true);
                shadow.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                shadow.setStrokeWidth(8);
                shadow.setDither(true);
                shadow.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                shadow.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
                shadow.setAntiAlias(true);

                int shadowRadius = radius + 2;
                RectF shadowOval = new RectF(mCenterX - shadowRadius, mCenterY - shadowRadius, mCenterX + shadowRadius, mCenterY + shadowRadius);
                canvas.drawArc(shadowOval, ClickedArc.CURRENT_ANGLE - 1, ClickedArc.ANGLE + 2, true, shadow);
                canvas.drawArc(oval, ClickedArc.CURRENT_ANGLE, ClickedArc.ANGLE, true, paint3);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (loadPieCfg) {
            mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i).setDataIndex(i);
            mPieMap.addPieSegment(i, value, currentAngle, angle + currentAngle);
        }
        currentAngle += angle;
    }

    radius -= (int) mRadius * decCoef;
    shortRadius -= mRadius * decCoef - 2;

    List<RectF> prevLabelsBounds = new ArrayList<RectF>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
        float value = (float) mDataset.getValue(i);
        float angle = (float) (value / total * 360);
        drawLabel(canvas, mDataset.getCategory(i), mRenderer, prevLabelsBounds, mCenterX, mCenterY, shortRadius / 2 + 50, longRadius / 2 + 50,
                labelCurrentAngle, angle, left, right, mRenderer.getLabelsColor(), paint, true, mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i));
        Point sPoint = mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i).getCenterPoint();
        Point ePoint = new Point((int) mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i).getTextWidth(), (int) mRenderer.getRenderers().get(i).getTextHeight());

        mPieMap.addLabelSegment(i, value, sPoint, ePoint);
        labelCurrentAngle += angle;
    }
    prevLabelsBounds.clear();
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve? And can you post your `onDraw()` method. How you are drawing on the canvas.

Comment: @AbirHasan Black Indicator not covering bottom

Comment: and your `onDraw()`?

Comment: @AbirHasan shall i send that file?

Comment: You can add the class or method and edit the question. Don't need to send anywhere.